# Docker, Communicate Two Containers Different Hosts Same Network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-machine

Good morning, everybody,

I was doing some testing with docker and I encountered a problem, for which I did not find a solution for the same case.

In my deployment, I want a server and a client to communicate, so far in different containers but on the same host. From the client I used the private IP of the server, and everything worked fine, here I show the compose:

Server:

```
   version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    image: python-server:ARM
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Client:

```
  version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    image: python-client:ARM
    ports:
      - 5040:5040
    volumes:
      - /dataf/1.csv:/app/1.csv:ro
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: server_default
```

However, when trying to do this communication, on two separate hosts [for example one on my host and one on virtual machine, both are on the same network] this fails. It is doubtful to me what the yamls should look like so that client and server could communicate with each other

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, Docker networks are local to a specific machine.  You may be able to set up an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) but this is an advanced setup, and you may be better served by using a cluster-aware container orchestrator like Kubernetes instead of trying to manually set this up.

Since both services publish `ports:`, from one machine you can call to the other machine's DNS name and the first published `ports:` number.

```yaml
# client/docker-compose.yml
services:
  client:
    environment:
      SERVER_URL: http://server-host.example.com:8080
```

You do not need special `networks:` setup here, and again you can't share a Docker network between the two containers on different hosts.  This setup actually doesn't care whether or not the server is running in a container or not, or if that URL is to a proxy that forwards to it.

Note that I've configured the URL in an environment variable.  You'll need to update your code to honor this.  The URL will be different in this multi-host setup, or in a single-host Compose-native setup, or if you're running the two processes side-by-side without Docker, or if you do eventually adopt Kubernetes.

Comment: Hi David,

I find your reply very helpful, thank you very much. Unfortunately it doesn't apply to my case, as both client and server are python applications. When I launch the client, from within the py file it connects to the server using a method for which it needs to know the IP of the server. As both hosts belong to the same network, I thought that this private IP of the server should be accessible by the client.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: It can use something like `os.getenv('SERVER_URL')` to retrieve the environment variable.  The IP address of the other host should work as well.